# results mismatched when retrieved dates from column of type character varying

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables,i want to get the min and max date stored in table1 cfrange column which is of type character varying.
table1 and table2 is mapped using sid. i want to get the max and min date range when compared with sid of table2.

table1:

```
sid  cfrange  

100   3390
101   8000
102   5/11/2010
103   11/12/2016
104   01/03/2016
105   4000
106   4000
107   03/12/2017
108   03/11/2016
109   4/04/2018
110   10/12/2016
```

table2:

```
sid  description

102  success
103  success
104  Proceeding
107  success
108  success
```

I tried as below but its not giving the correct min and max value.Please advice.

```
select max(t1.cfrange),min(t1.cfrange) from table1 t1,table2 t2 where t1.sid=t2.sid;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should join two tables and cast cfrange as a date and cross your fingers. (May be you must format it as a date before to cast it).

> ```
> create table table1 (sid int,   cfrange varchar(30));  
> insert into table1 values
> (100,   '3390'),
> (101,   '8000'),
> (102,   '5/11/2010'),
> (103,   '11/12/2016'),
> (104,   '01/03/2016'),
> (105,   '4000'),
> (106,   '4000'),
> (107,   '03/12/2017'),
> (108,   '03/11/2016'),
> (109,   '4/04/2018'),
> (110,   '10/12/2016');
>
> create table table2 (sid int,   description varchar(30));  
> insert into table2 values
> (102,  'success'),
> (103,  'success'),
> (104, 'Proceeding'),
> (107,  'success'),
> (108,  'success');
> ```

> ```
> select 'Min' as caption, min(cfrange) as value
> from   (select     table1.sid, table1.cfrange::date
>         from       table1
>         inner join table2
>         on         table1.sid = table2.sid) tt
> UNION ALL
> select 'Max' as caption, max(cfrange) as value
> from   (select     table1.sid, table1.cfrange::date
>         from       table1
>         inner join table2
>         on         table1.sid = table2.sid) tt;
> ```
>
> ```
> caption | value     
> :------ | :---------
> Min     | 2010-11-05
> Max     | 2017-12-03
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=62931b4251a16f9d371822c74848f80f)*

Comment: @Mc Nets -  It is not executing, it says FROM-clause entry for table ..can it be written as sql squery instead of starting with clause "with tt as..

Comment: I'm sorry, but the result is not correct. Infact it's displaying date that is not existing in the database columns. @MC Nets.

Comment: The supplied data in your question is good? can I use it to set up an example?

Comment: Yes,data is good. You can set up the example. I'm using postgres5 database,results i see is not correct, even when i executed subquery the date's it displayed are not correct. I think problem lies with to_date.

Comment: My cfrange column is of type character varying. I modified the table as create table table1 (sid int,   cfrange character varying(30)) in fiddle u posted and the result displayed is wrong.Please advice.thanks.@Mc Nets

Comment: Please, copy and paste the link to the dbfiddle, because I've changed it in mine, and it works. http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=52280dc5915bc833e43bf172fabd753c

Comment: @Mc Nets - It's not working on my database which is weird.I have accepted the answer as it works in dbfiddle. I could not able to figure out still y its not working on mine....thanks for the help.Do you suggest any way to find out why its not showing in my DB.

Comment: I'd suggest to evaluate data returned by the subquery without converting it to a date type, just to have a look.

Comment: McNets..subquery is returning  correct results when to_date function is removed..with to_date data dispalyed is wrong.

Comment: try by casting cfrange to date on this way; `cfrange::date`

Comment: Appreciate your help.Finally code is working with ::date .Please let me know if anything need to be changed.Thanks. select min(cfrange::date) as min_cf,
       max(cfrange::date) as max_cf
from   (select     table1.sid, table1.cfrange::date as cfrange
        from       table1
        inner join table2
        on         table1.sid = table2.sid) tt;

Comment: can i do UNION ALL on the same query and get the result in a single column(displaying min and max date values in single column)  instead of displaying min and max values in separate columns. I was trying to use 'union all' but of no luck.Please advice.